# UDP lost data restore

Tags: udp, real-time, sensors, restore

I'm making application that receives sensors data (like gyroscope) via UDP and I need to restore data that was lost.
How to do that?

For example, how to handle it in space rocket? You can't ask for retransmission because it will take too long when device is in space.

Sorry for grammar.

//EDIT

I forgot to say that I send packets in fixed frequency so device knows when it lost something

Answer (score 0):

For connections which have a very high latency or for unidirectional connections the data are usually encoded so that transmission errors can not only be detected but also mostly repaired. In the simplest case you just send the same data again and again in the hope that after some time they get successfully received by the peer. But there are more intelligent encodings than this. To get some ideas look at how RAID-5 and similar technologies work where even if a disk crashes the data still can be reproduced.

Comment: Sending the same packet isn't a solution when something is blocking (e.g. some physical obstacle) connection.

So RAID-5 also isn't a answer when we lose whole packet

Comment: Sending the same packet does not mean that you have to send it immediately. You could also sent it later. At the end the protocol you need to develop highly depends on the kind of errors you expect, that is data corruption can be handled by error-correcting codes, data loss by repeating data later in some way etc. The more errors you expect the more overhead the protocol will have and the more buffering and intelligence in reconstructing the data has to be applied. There is no magic solution which just handles all of these independent from the characteristics of your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for a video communications product many years ago: For each packet, numbered P0, P1, P2, etc, you choose how long a burst of loss you need to tolerate. Let's use 3 packets as an example.

You start the communication by sending P0 through P5 as usual, but then P6 has extra data attached to it: the xor of P0 and P3. P6 has the xor of P1 and P4, etc. If you suffer a loss of any three packets, they can be reconstructed. If Pn, Pn+1 and Pn+2 are lost, you can xor Pn+3 with the "extra" data on Pn+6 to recover packet Pn.

If you can afford to pay memory and bandwidth in favor of maximizing reliability, I'd recommend having each packet carry multiple xors. For example, Pn might be shipped with the xor of Pn-3 and Pn-6 AND another xor of Pn-12 and Pn-24.

You can also use a feedback mechanism from the received that allows it to tell the sender to change its recovery characteristics, sending more or less recovery data and adjusting the intervals.